# Dynamically Create A Color Legend Based off of a collection

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a legend based on a collection,the code below goes into a Shapefile and pulls specific column data then we assign a color to the data. this i made within the controller and i was wondering if i can create an HTML legend based of of this collection, the way im thinking of doing it is creating radio buttons with each of the layers that we want legends for. i Know this may be vague but i dont really know how to describe it.

any suggestions will be greatly appreciated

```
 private Collection<ValueItem> colorSelect(Collection<Feature> allFeatures, string layercode,Collection<ValueItem> valueItems)
    {

        List<string> values = new List<string>();
        foreach (Feature f in allFeatures)
        {
            if (f.ColumnValues.ContainsKey(layercode))
            {
                if (!values.Contains(f.ColumnValues[layercode].ToString()))
                {
                    values.Add(f.ColumnValues[layercode].ToString());
                }
            }

        }


        if (values.Count > 0)
        {
            Random randomGen = new Random();
            int count = 0;
            foreach (string esnCode in values)
            {
                //int count = 0;
                if (count == 0)
                {
                    ValueItem item = new ValueItem(esnCode, AreaStyles.CreateSimpleAreaStyle(GeoColor.StandardColors.Green, GeoColor.StandardColors.Black, 3));
                    valueItems.Add(item);

                }
                if (count == 1)
                {
                    ValueItem item = new ValueItem(esnCode, AreaStyles.CreateSimpleAreaStyle(GeoColor.StandardColors.Pink, GeoColor.StandardColors.Black, 3));
                    valueItems.Add(item);

                }
                if (count == 2)
                {
                    ValueItem item = new ValueItem(esnCode, AreaStyles.CreateSimpleAreaStyle(GeoColor.StandardColors.Blue, GeoColor.StandardColors.Black, 3));
                    valueItems.Add(item);

                }
                if (count == 3)
                {
                    ValueItem item = new ValueItem(esnCode, AreaStyles.CreateSimpleAreaStyle(GeoColor.StandardColors.Yellow, GeoColor.StandardColors.Black, 3));
                    valueItems.Add(item);

                }
                if (count == 4)
                {
                    ValueItem item = new ValueItem(esnCode, AreaStyles.CreateSimpleAreaStyle(GeoColor.StandardColors.Violet, GeoColor.StandardColors.Black, 3));
                    valueItems.Add(item);

                }
                if (count == 5)
                {
                    ValueItem item = new ValueItem(esnCode, AreaStyles.CreateSimpleAreaStyle(GeoColor.StandardColors.Red, GeoColor.StandardColors.Black, 3));
                    valueItems.Add(item);

                }
                if (count == 6)
                {
                    ValueItem item = new ValueItem(esnCode, AreaStyles.CreateSimpleAreaStyle(GeoColor.StandardColors.Aqua, GeoColor.StandardColors.Black, 3));
                    valueItems.Add(item);

                }
                if (count == 7)
                {
                    ValueItem item = new ValueItem(esnCode, AreaStyles.CreateSimpleAreaStyle(GeoColor.StandardColors.Black, GeoColor.StandardColors.Black, 3));
                    valueItems.Add(item);

                }
                if (count == 8)
                {
                    ValueItem item = new ValueItem(esnCode, AreaStyles.CreateSimpleAreaStyle(GeoColor.StandardColors.Brown, GeoColor.StandardColors.Black, 3));
                    valueItems.Add(item);

                }
                if (count == 9)
                {
                    ValueItem item = new ValueItem(esnCode, AreaStyles.CreateSimpleAreaStyle(GeoColor.StandardColors.Coral, GeoColor.StandardColors.Black, 3));
                    valueItems.Add(item);

                }
                if (count == 10)
                {
                    ValueItem item = new ValueItem(esnCode, AreaStyles.CreateSimpleAreaStyle(GeoColor.StandardColors.DarkKhaki, GeoColor.StandardColors.Black, 3));
                    valueItems.Add(item);

                }
                count++;
            }

        }
        return (valueItems);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, once you fetch your color data, you have to pass it to the view and do something with it.
you have 2 options of passing it:

1. As Model
2. in ViewBag

Doesnt matter what option you choose, but lets say we pass it in view bag.

```
public ActionResult ColorsLegend()
{
     var listOfColors = colorSelect(args..);
     ViewBag.colorList = listOfColors;

     return View();
}
```

in the view you can iterate through this list of colors and do what you want actually. F.e let us create a list of color blocks and names for that color

```
@foreach(var item in ViewBag.colorList){
   <div style='background-color:@item.colorValue;width:100px;height:20px;float:left;'></div>
   <span style='float:left;'> - @item.colorName </span>
}
```

Comment: im sorry to ask but how would you do this with a model?

Comment: If you have a model, then in the controller you should pass it to the view like this: return View(myModelObject);
and in the view on the top you should specify what kind of model that view expects and instead of ViewBag.colorList use Model.ColorList or just Model if the Model is a list of colors itself :)